# ext4magic segfault

Tags: linux, deleted-files, extundelete

I am trying to restore a directory I accidentally deleted which contained many files. Ironically this was a fat finger error while trying to set up a backup! I am following the instructions [here](http://ext4magic.sourceforge.net/howto_en.html#A_directory_with_a_huge_amount_of_files_is_recursive_deleted):

The ext4magic command to generate a histogram is successful:

```
[root] /mnt/reos-storage-2 $ ext4magic /dev/sda2 -H -a $(date -d "-70minutes" +%s)
Filesystem in use: /dev/sda2

|-----------c_time  Histogram-----------------  after  --------------------  Wed Jun 23 10:42:35 2021
1624441775 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 10:49:35 2021
1624442195 :       43 |**************************************************|   Wed Jun 23 10:56:35 2021
1624442615 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:03:35 2021
1624443035 :        1 |**                                                |   Wed Jun 23 11:10:35 2021
1624443455 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:17:35 2021
1624443875 :        3 |****                                              |   Wed Jun 23 11:24:35 2021
1624444295 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:31:35 2021
1624444715 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:38:35 2021
1624445135 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:45:35 2021
1624445555 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:52:35 2021


|-----------d_time  Histogram-----------------  after  --------------------  Wed Jun 23 10:42:35 2021
1624441775 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 10:49:35 2021
1624442195 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 10:56:35 2021
1624442615 :        1 |*                                                 |   Wed Jun 23 11:03:35 2021
1624443035 :     9380 |**************************************************|   Wed Jun 23 11:10:35 2021
1624443455 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:17:35 2021
1624443875 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:24:35 2021
1624444295 :        1 |*                                                 |   Wed Jun 23 11:31:35 2021
1624444715 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:38:35 2021
1624445135 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:45:35 2021
1624445555 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:52:35 2021


|-----------cr_time Histogram-----------------  after  --------------------  Wed Jun 23 10:42:35 2021
1624441775 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 10:49:35 2021
1624442195 :       33 |**************************************************|   Wed Jun 23 10:56:35 2021
1624442615 :        1 |**                                                |   Wed Jun 23 11:03:35 2021
1624443035 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:10:35 2021
1624443455 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:17:35 2021
1624443875 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:24:35 2021
1624444295 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:31:35 2021
1624444715 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:38:35 2021
1624445135 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:45:35 2021
1624445555 :        0 |                                                  |   Wed Jun 23 11:52:35 2021
ext4magic : EXIT_SUCCESS
```

However, any further commands essentially end in a segfault

```
[root] /mnt/reos-storage-2 $ ext4magic /dev/sda2 -a 1624442615 -f r sftp_data -l
Filesystem in use: /dev/sda2

Using  internal Journal at Inode 8
Activ Time after  : Wed Jun 23 11:03:35 2021
Activ Time before : Wed Jun 23 11:56:09 2021
Segmentation fault
```

Is there anything I can do?

---

**More Background**

As background, I got to this point with roughly the following steps.

I unmounted the file system as quickly as I could after frantic googling. Initially I did this with

```
umount -l /mnt/reos-storage-1
```

I used the `-l` option because umount could not unmount the partition which was still in use. Next I did

```
fuser -cuk /mnt/reos-storage-1/
```

Next I ran

```
fsck /dev/sda2
```

which is not recommended by ext4magic actually.

Next I tried to recover the files with `extundelete` which failed

```
[root] /mnt/reos-storage-2 $ extundelete --restore-directory /mnt/reos-storage-1/sftp_data /dev/sda2
NOTICE: Extended attributes are not restored.
Loading filesystem metadata ... 29027 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 0 descriptors loaded.
extundelete: Extent block checksum does not match extent block while finding inode for mnt
extundelete: Extent block checksum does not match extent block while finding inode for mnt
Failed to restore file /mnt/reos-storage-1/sftp_data
Could not find correct inode number past inode 2.
Try altering the filename to one of the entries listed below.
File name                                       | Inode number | Deleted status
extundelete: Operation not permitted while restoring directory.
extundelete: Operation not permitted when trying to examine filesystem
[root] /mnt/reos-storage-2 $ man umount
[root] /mnt/reos-storage-2 $ extundelete --restore-all /dev/sda2
NOTICE: Extended attributes are not restored.
Loading filesystem metadata ... 29027 groups loaded.
Loading journal descriptors ... 0 descriptors loaded.
Searching for recoverable inodes in directory / ... 
0 recoverable inodes found.
Looking through the directory structure for deleted files ... 
0 recoverable inodes still lost.
No files were undeleted.
```

I then installed ext4magic using apt and ran the following command as in the instructions to make a backup of the journal

```
debugfs -R "dump <8> /tmp/sda2.journal" /dev/sda2
```

Comment: I got exact error. Did you find reason why this error comes up?